# NetworkManager: error while loading shared libraries: libsoup-2.4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, no-response

I got this problem when i did this:sudo unlink /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1,and then the ubuntu system seemed to be abnormal,the network icon was disappeared,and some icon i clicked without any response.Is here anyone who can help me?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstall libsoup2.4-1 in your system

```
sudo apt-get install libsoup2.4-1
```

Or you can remove libsoup2.4-1 from synaptic package manager and reinstall same.

Or you can make link

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1.5.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1
```

Comment: I'm so sorry.I got another problem when i opened eclipse after doing so,and it's crash,here is the error log:
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
SIGSEGV (0xb) atpc=0x00007ff18cd9e2a1,pid=29992,tid=140678082311936
JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b32) (build 1.7.0_65
-b32)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 
compressed oops)
Problematic frame:C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. 
...

Comment: Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable 

core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.